# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/plugins/surefire/api/AbstractSurefireParser

Tags: scala, sbt, sonarqube, sonar-runner, scoverage

I installed SonarQube Server 4.5 and SonarQube Runner 2.4. I added sonar-scoverage-plugin-1.1.0.jar in sonar plugins directory. In /opt/sonar-runner/sonar-runner.properties, I uncommented

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000.
```

I tried to use sonar -runner for this sample project https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin/tree/master/samples/sbt/multi-module.

I executed two commands

$ sbt clean scoverage:test

$ sonar-runner

I got this exception

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.542s
Final Memory: 59M/343M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://localhost:9000/batch/project?   key=com.buransky:multi-module&preview=false]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:89)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:81)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.referential.DefaultProjectReferentialsLoader.load(DefaultProjectReferentialsLoader.java:55)
at org.sonar.batch.referential.ProjectReferentialsProvider.provide(ProjectReferentialsProvider.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:677)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:198)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:102)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/batch/project?key=com.buransky:multi-module&preview=false]. Response code: 500
at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:281)
at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:87)
... 59 more
```

Can anyone  help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Added [sonar-surefire-plugin-3.3.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/plugins/sonar-surefire-plugin/3.3.2/sonar-surefire-plugin-3.3.2.jar) in sonar plugins.